# Automatically set the scale of an element based on the height of the viewport

Tags: jquery, height, transform, scale, viewport

To scale an element with CSS based on various viewport heights is tedious to say the least, and should IMO not be needed. Then again, I might be totally wrong.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to use jQuery in order to automatically set the scale of an element based on the height of the viewport?

I have checked every link I can find here on Stackflow to no avail and I have checked out http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ which seems like a viable option but I don't know how to calculate the height and turn it into a value so I can use it for CSS transformation scale.
I am not sure, but I might need "check points" so that a specific height will be a preset value.

I will also need to be able to adjust the scale manually so I can adjust the scaling to make the element fit most viewports.

This is my example:
http://testsiten.se/modernaglas/images/showcase/bedroom/

I need the whole content within the class .scales to scale according to the height of the viewport and also update if orientation is changed.

The width is the same as the height so it shouldn't pose a problem since it won't ever be wider than the height.

I do NOT want to change the height of `.scales` as that would break the whole design.

I have done some real crappy CSS media queries, which haven't been cleaned up since I figured it just HAVE to be easier to do all of this with jQuery.

This is my CSS.

```
body, html{ background-color: #333333; font-family: tahoma; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
img{background: none}
h1 {font-size: 18px; margin: 0; font-weight: normal; text-align: center}
#ChangableElements {width: 958px; margin:0 auto; }
#navigation {background-color: #bdc7c9; color: #6e7377;padding: 7px 8px 5px 21px;}
#navigation div div {display: inline-block;}
#navigation div div span{display: block;}
.nav_glas, .nav_ram {display: inline-block;font-size: 13px;text-align: center;}
.nav_glas div, .nav_ram div{padding: 1px 13px 0 10px;}
.nav_glas div a, .nav_ram div a{display: inline-block; margin: 8px 0 10px;}
.nav_ram{float: right;}
.work_area {margin-bottom: 0; background: url("images/bg_image.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; height: auto;width: 958px;}

.border, .grid{margin-top: 0px;position: absolute;top: 0;}
.grid_on {width: 50px}
.headers h1{display: inline-block;}
.headers h1:first-child{float: left; margin-left: 10px; }
.headers{display: block!important;padding: 0 !important;}


.hidden {display: none;}
```

One of my Media Queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 719px) and (max-device-width : 721px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
div.scales
{
   transform: scale(0.37);
   -ms-transform: scale(0.37); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.37); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform: scale(0.37); /* Opera */
   -moz-transform: scale(0.37); /* Firefox */
   transform-origin: top center;
   -ms-transform-origin: top center;
   -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
   -o-transform-origin: top center;
   -moz-transform-origin: top center;
}
}
```

This is my jQuery:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeImage(el, img_url) {
        $(document).find(el).attr('src', img_url);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // add color btns event
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.spegel').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/spegel.png');
        });
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.vit_traskiva').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/vit_traskiva.png');
        });
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.vitt_glas').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/vitt_glas.png');
        });
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.metall_glas').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/metall_gra.png');
        });
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.gult_glas').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/gult_glas.png');
        });
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.rott_glas').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/rott_glas.png');
        });
        $('.nav_glas').find('a.svart_glas').click(function(){
            changeImage('#mirror', 'images/svart_glas.png');
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(el, img_url) {
        $(document).find(el).attr('src', img_url);
    }
    var app = {
        isActive: function(el){
            if($(el).hasClass('active')) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        whoActive: function(){
            return $('.active').attr('id');
        },
        change_grid: function(image){
            changeImage('#grid', image);
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // add color btns event
        $('.nav_ram').find('a.vit').click(function(){

            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            changeImage('#border', 'images/vit_el.png');
            app.change_grid('images/grid_vit.png');


        });
        $('.nav_ram').find('a.silvermatt').click(function(){
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            changeImage('#border', 'images/silver_el.png');
            app.change_grid('images/grid_silvermatt.png');
        });
        $('.nav_ram').find('a.svart').click(function(){
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            changeImage('#border', 'images/svart_blank_el.png');
            app.change_grid('images/grid_svart.png');
        });

        // grid_turn_on event
        $('.grid_turn_on').click(function(event){

            var grid_on = $('.grid_on'); // div el
            var grid = $('#grid');
            var is_hidden = false;

            if(grid.hasClass('hidden')) {
                is_hidden = true;
            }
            else {
                is_hidden = false;
            }

            log(app.whoActive());
            switch (app.whoActive()) {
                case 'vit':
                    log('is vit');
                    if(is_hidden) {
                        grid.removeClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_on.jpg');
                        changeImage('#grid', 'images/grid_silvermatt.png');
                    } else {
                        grid.addClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_off.jpg');
                    }


                    break;
                case 'silvermatt':
                    log('is silver');
                    if(is_hidden) {
                        grid.removeClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_on.jpg');
                        changeImage('#grid', 'images/grid_silvermatt.png');
                    } else {
                        grid.addClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_off.jpg');
                    }

                    break;
                case 'svart':
                    log('is svart');
                    if(is_hidden) {
                        grid.removeClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_on.jpg');
                        changeImage('#grid', 'images/grid_svart.png');
                    } else {
                        grid.addClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_off.jpg');
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if(is_hidden) {
                        grid.removeClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_on.jpg');
                    }
                    else {
                        grid.addClass('hidden');
                        grid_on.find('span').empty().append('Ja/Nej');
                        grid_on.find('img').attr('src','images/grid_off.jpg');
                    }
            }



        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>mirror</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="scales" id="ChangableElements">
        <div class="work_area">
            <img src="images/grid_svart.png" alt="" id="grid" class="grid">
            <img src="images/svart_blank_el.png" alt="" id="border" class="border">
            <img src="images/vitt_glas.png" alt="" id="mirror">
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="nav_glas">
                <h1>Välj färg på glas/skiva</h1>
                <div><a class="spegel"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Spegel</span></div>
                <div><a class="vit_traskiva"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Vit träskiva</span></div>
                <div><a class="vitt_glas"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Vitt glas</span></div>
                <div><a class="metall_glas"><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Metallgrått glas</span></div>
                <div><a class="gult_glas"><img src="images/pic5.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Gult glas</span></div>
                <div><a class="rott_glas"><img src="images/pic6.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Rött glas</span></div>
                <div><a class="svart_glas"><img src="images/pic7.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Svart glas</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_ram" id="tfoot">
                <div class="headers">
                    <h1>Spröjs</h1>
                    <h1>Välj färg på dörrens ram</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_on"><a class="grid_turn_on" ><img src="images/grid_on.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Ja/Nej</span></div>
                <div><a class="vit" id="vit"><img src="images/pic2_1.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Vit blank</span></div>
                <div><a class="silvermatt" id="silvermatt"><img src="images/pic2_2.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Silvermatt</span></div>
                <div><a class="svart" id="svart"><img src="images/pic2_3.jpg" alt=""></a><span>Svart blank</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As one can see I have alot of elements inside the .scales and there is also a background image in there. This is why I need it to scale rather than to set the height because there are so many elements dependent on the scale of the .scales.

I hope I made myself understood now. :D

Edit:
Finally learned some jQ in order to get this functional.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).on('resize', function(){
                var vpheight = $(window).height();
                var vpwidth = $(window).width();

        if(vpwidth>vpheight) {
          // Landscape
            var height = $(window).height() * 0.00148;
            var width = height / 2 * -958;
            $('.scales').css('transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-ms-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-o-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('#ChangableElements').css({'left': width  + 'px'});
        } else if(vpwidth <=720 && vpheight > 569 ) {
            var height = $(window).height() * 0.000675;
            var width = height / 2 * -958;
            $('.scales').css('transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-ms-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-o-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('#ChangableElements').css({'left': width  + 'px'});
        } else {
          // Portrait
            var height = $(window).height() * 0.000895;
            var width = height / 2 * -958;
            $('.scales').css('transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-ms-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-o-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('.scales').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');
            $('#ChangableElements').css({'left': width  + 'px'});
        }
        }).resize()
    });
    </script>
```

The weird vpwidth <=720 && vpheight > 569 is for forcing my Samsung Galaxy S3 function properly. Strange resolution...

Comment: Please post the relevant code here instead of on a third party website.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to scale a top level element to some percentage of the viewport height. Just set the height property on the html and body elements to 100% and then any child of the body can use a percentage height and that will correspond to the viewport height.

For example, something like the CSS below would make a div with class *scale* fill the height of the viewport. [Example codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klnyp)

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.scale {
  background-color:orange;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you aren't too worried about older browsers, you can also just viewport units anywhere in the markup. This makes things a lot easier, and also allows you to set a width based on the viewport hight or vice versa.

For example, a square with sides matching the viewport height could be implemented like this:

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
.scale {
  background-color:orange;
  width:100vh;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

That said, viewport units don't always respond immediately to resizing and can behave unexpectedly when scrollbars are involved, so there are tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).height()`, like in:

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
```

Then change the width according to the height and set both properties, something like:

```
$("#theElement").css({'width':varWidth, 'height':varHeight});
```

Comment: Hi JEES. No, I cannot set the height as I must scale everything inside the container div accordingly. It also contains a div with a background image, which makes setting the height not a functional way of doing it.

Comment: @AmritRosell, you can set percentage scaling of background image, like `100%` also in every technique there are advantages and disadvantages, you asked about scaling with jQuery as you said and i am quoting "*since I figured it just HAVE to be easier to do all of this with jQuery.*"

Comment: But if it was me i wouldn't do it like this, i'd go with server side detection or media queries.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have explored scaling the height with jQuery by setting height and width, but what I meant was altering the transform: scale; not changing the height and width through jQuery.

I have also written alot of media queries for setting various transform: scale, but there is just so many different resolutions I find it rather crippling writing so many different media queries when all I really want to do is adjust the transorm: scale; based on the height of the viewport.

What server side slution would you instead use?

Comment: Finally I managed to get everything working properly. :D

Too long to write here, so added it in my original question. Thanks for leading me in the right direction JEES...

Comment: Happy for you, just a tip.. you'd consider caching your `$('.scale')` and use chaining like this `$('.scales').css('transform', 'scale(' + height + ')').css('-ms-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + height + ')');` . Also note that you can set more than one csss property in one .css statement. like >> `.css({'margin-top':'-2px', 'background-color':'#f00'});`